# Annoying OneDrive popup on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have Windows 10 with Office installed (utilizing Office365).  I have never installed OneDrive explicitly, but every now and then I see this popup on my laptop:

[image: Set up OneDrive]

I don't want to use OneDrive.  How do I get rid of it permanently?  In Add/Remove programs I don't see an option to uninstall OneDrive.

Comment: It doesn't matter that Microsoft Office is installed. I see the popup and I've never had the office suite installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Windows 10 Professional (although this also applies to the Enterprise and Education versions), there is a relatively simple way to turn off OneDrive:

1. Hold <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type `gpedit.msc` in the search field.
3. Right-click the result and `Run as administrator` to open the `Local Group Policy Editor`
4. Navigate to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OneDrive`
5. Enable the policy titled **Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage**

On the other hand, since the release of the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703) in April 2017, Windows 10 Home users can now utilize the following method to remove OneDrive:

> Head to either Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a Program or Settings > Apps > Apps & features. You’ll see a **Microsoft OneDrive** program appear in the list of installed software. Click it and click the “Uninstall” button.
>
> [image: OneDrive Uninstall]
>
> Windows will immediately uninstall OneDrive, and the OneDrive icon will disappear from the notification area.
>
> (If you ever want to reinstall OneDrive in the future, you’ll need to run the OneDrive installer buried in the Windows system folder. Just head to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ folder on a 64-bit version of Windows 10 or the C:\Windows\System32 folder on a 32-bit version of Windows 10. Double-click the “OneDriveSetup.exe” file here and Windows will reinstall OneDrive.)

(Source: [How to Disable OneDrive and Remove It From File Explorer on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/225973/how-to-disable-onedrive-and-remove-it-from-file-explorer-on-windows-10/))

Comment: howtogeek.com updated their article, the answer is out of date.

Comment: @user598527,  I appreciate the feedback. To clarify, the original accepted answer was still accurate, but I have now included the new method within Windows 10 Home that is available since the Windows 10 Creators Update was released.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: I am the user who posted the original question. Your original answer worked for me, but stopped working after I installed creator's update. Even with that policy enabled, the onedrive popup started popping up again. I have now uninstalled onedrive - let's see what happens.

Comment: @user93353, that should get the job done.  The staff at *How-To Geek* is very reliable about the accuracy of their articles, and they updated that one following the release of the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703).

Comment: We have this on my mother's Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive is built in to Windows 10, so it can't be uninstalled. But you can hide it and stop the sync process, so it stays hidden. 
To do this, turn off all the OneDrive settings and remove the OneDrive folder from File Explorer.

1. In the Notifications area on the bottom of the Windows screen, right-click the OneDrive icon. 
   You might have to click the Show Hidden Icons arrow to find OneDrive.

[image]

2. Click Settings, and on the Settings tab, uncheck all the boxes under General.
3. On the Auto save tab, set the Documents and Pictures lists to This PC only, and uncheck the other boxes.
4. On the Account tab, click Choose folders.
5. In the Sync your OneDrive files to this PC box, check and uncheck the box at Sync all files and folders in my OneDrive. 
   (The first check selects all the boxes, then the uncheck clears them all.) Click OK to close the box and return to settings.

   This step removes all OneDrive files from your computer, but leaves them on OneDrive.com.
6. Click OK to save your changes in the Settings box.
7. Open the Settings box again: In the Notifications area, right-click the OneDrive icon, click Settings. On the Account tab, click Unlink OneDrive. 
   Close the Welcome to OneDrive box that appears.
8. Open File Explorer, right-click OneDrive, and then click Properties.

   On the General tab, next to Attributes, check the Hidden box. This hides OneDrive from File Explorer.
9. One more time, back in the Notifications area, right-click the OneDrive icon and click Exit. This removes the OneDrive icon from the Notifications area.

For more information check this [Microsoft page.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-or-uninstall-OneDrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the system tray icon for One Drive and select settings. In the window there is an option to have One Drive run on startup. Uncheck this option. Then right click the system tray icon for One Drive again and select exit.