# PC doesn't boot because of accidental deletion of win 10 registry files

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally deleted windows registry or system files. Now windows doesn't boot and Windows 10 starting dots encircle only. Though my deleted files lie in the Recycle Bin, I don't know how to restore them.

Comment: Can you boot into Safe Mode? If not, you will need to boot an external system, such as a diagnostic disc and use this to recover the files, though you may need to do this manually, since the external system may not know the original locations of the deleted files. Otherwise, you will need to recover from a back-up. If all else fails, you may need to reinstall, using the option to preserve programs and settings, but do a full disc back-up first, so you don't lose anything more.

Comment: @ AFH.... "you may need to reinstall, using the option to preserve programs and settings" Are you talking about System Reset?

Comment: BTW I haven't yet tried system reset.

Comment: If you don't mind a quick question to address the root cause of the problem (and help avoid it in the future), how did you *"accidentally deleted windows registry or system files."* ??

Comment: I uninstalled some softwares including OneDrive with Revo uninstaller. Since Revo also searches for and deletes leftovers, I doubt it is the uninstallation that led to the problem and caused deletion of the system files as well.

Comment: I blindly trusted the Revo findings of leftovers and marked them all for deletion.

Comment: @Abdullah1 - No, I'm talking about using an installation disc to install over the top of your current installation without losing what is already installed, but this should be a last resort after other recovery methods have failed.

Comment: If it is really *that* important for you to remove OneDrive, [there are much better ways](https://superuser.com/questions/1151249/annoying-onedrive-popup-on-windows-10) to do it.  Utilizing a third-party tool (even a prominent one like Revo Uninstaller) to remove built-in operating system files and registry entries was simply an accident waiting to happen.  I'm sorry that this happened to you, but hopefully it is a valuable lesson regarding what **not** to do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You will need on another computer to create bootable rescue media,
boot with it and try to restore the files.

Some software which might help:

- [EaseUS Data Recovery Software with Bootable Media](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/recover-data-from-a-hard-drive-that-wont-boot.html)
- [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/how-to-recover-deleted-files-from-pc.php)

I never tested these utilities in your situation, so cannot guarantee that they
will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the hard drive to another Windows pc via usb, once windows mounts it and assigns a drive letter, it will also mount the recycle bin of that drive, then you can simply open the recycle bin on the host OS and pick the files you deleted to be restored. Remove the drive and put back in original pc, it should boot now.